# What would be a good reason why all life has to stay below ground?

Tags: caves

I want a natural reason why nearly all life would be in caves, or built structures beneath the surface. Here's what I'm looking for:

1. The surface of my planet should instantly kill most species. They can't come up, even for a moment.
2. The air in the caves should be comfortable for life, despite having holes where bits of sunlight come in.
3. There should be aquifers and water sources underground, but hardly any rainfall as to not flood the caves.

Comment: You shouldn't ask questions where the answer is provided in the question itself and then expect more. Point 1) is the answer to your question.

Comment: "_Instantly lethal outdoors_" and "_...but open skylights are absolutely fine_" is an awkward combination.

Comment: Try looking up "actinic stars", though may need to modify the requirement Starfish mentions.

Comment: @L.Dutch I don't understand how that provides the answer to my question. I'm asking why everything would be forced to live underground and die when they go up to the surface. I don't know the answer, that's why I asked.

Comment: Research suggestion: the video game Arx Fatalis. The background for the world is that the surface is non-hospitable to life after the sun failed and all surface inhabitants had to move underground. Although short trips on the surface are *possible* but very rare.

Comment: does it need to be the whole planet or just a large portion of it?

Comment: A desert on Earth is like that. Things shelter during the day because it is too hot and too dry. Have a look at the Qanats of Iran.

Comment: If you really mean being on the surface would 'instantly' kill most species, two queries arise.

How are the killed 'most' different from the surviving species?

What could 'instantly kill' most species but something like sand-storms?

Radiation might seem obvious and doesn't that depend on whether you equate 'instantly kill' with 'instantly inflict a lethal condition upon'?

To me, 'instantly kill' means you drop down dead right now, which doesn't include radiation poisoning.

Answer (score 6):

## Ever-present Sand Storms

The wind on the surface is so strong, and it carries so much sand, that it will literally rip the flesh off your skin. Most organisms cannot survive there. `#Not at all inspired by dune`

Lets see whether this meets your conditions:

1. Instantly kills most species. Yes, I think that having your flesh sandblasted off would kill most species.
2. Air in the caves comfortable for life. Yes, once you're away from the wind, the sand doesn't stay in the air, so its fine. As long as the blowing sand in the air doesn't block the sunlight there's little reason why it couldn't get through some holes. You might get some sand falling in too, but that's nothing a broom couldn't fix.
3. Aquifers without rainfall. The easiest way to justify this is that rain only falls in high mountains which collect into the the aquifers, and obviously any caves nearby those high mountains aren't nice places to live because of flooding. But all the other caves don't get flooded as the rain doesn't really fall there. This is still a bit of a problem as you would have to explain why there are caves, as the most common reason caves exist is that they were formed by flowing water. So you'd need to have a reason why you have caves, but they don't have water. Maybe just the fact that there may have been different circumstances long ago.

Here are a few reasons that other things don't work.

1. Radiation: this would still allow people to go outside at night, or with a barrier to block the radiation. Especially in a circumstance where holes can let light into the caves safely.
2. Extreme Temperature (hot or cold): This would make the caves nearer the surface to not be comfortable for life as they would approach the outside temp.
3. Pestilence: That would constitute a lot of life living on the surface. Both the microbes themselves and whatever food source keeps them going at significant levels.

Comment: and where is the infinite supply of sand? and will quickly be pulverized into dust.

Answer (score 2):

Make it a tidally locked planet orbiting a red dwarf. Life would be confined to the twilight zone at the equator. Solar flares might torch anything unlucky enough to be on the surface at the wrong time, and strip off much of the atmosphere.

If the planet had a libration about the tidally locked position as the Moon does about the Earth, then the twilight zone might move a bit, giving something a bit like seasons in the twilight zone.

You do not have to go far underground to be safe. It may be no picnic. Water would condense on the shadowed side, and may have to be fetched as ice. Maybe even the atmosphere would condense on the far side. If the atmosphere is fine in the twilight zone, then you might come out of the cave and feel the sunshine for a bit. Deep underground, you would have the bunkers to ride out the particularly massive solar flares.

Comment: If there's atmosphere, it'll transport heat onto the dark side which will be rather less frozen and inhospitable than you might think. If there's not enough atmosphere to support that, then having open skylights into your caves presents a problem for things that need to breathe or photosynthesize...

Comment: The atmosphere is supposed to be good. I don't know how that works, but the caves were not hermetically sealed. I would have thought all the atmosphere would go to the dark side and condense there. But we don't really know what conditions are like on these planets. There are a lot of red dwarf stars, and they last a long time, so there is a chance that one might be habitable in some part of its life.

Comment: We don't know what conditions are like, but it is possible to make some pretty good simulations and a lot of people have done just that over the past 30-odd years. Its worth hunting down some papers on the subject. Getting an atmosphere to condense out seems unlikely unless the world were very distant from its star and the sunside were very cold, but that doesn't sound like a world on which you'd find a whole lot of cave life.

Comment: @StarfishPrime There have been lots of papers, but the flares from Red Dwarfs are a fairly recent discovery. A lot of the simulations are for planets in a steady state. I would not be surprised if predictions changed again.